# Javascript: getElementsByClassName() and querySelector() return the result only after click to the DOM

Tags: javascript, chromium, getelementsbyclassname, selectors-api

I found this only on Google Doc.

[image: getElementsByClassName Google Doc Chromium after click]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB0bRhNTXUU

Also tested in the Guest mode without any extensions and in Chromium 66 - the same weird behaviour.

Works correctly in Firefox and Opera.

This is a defect of Chromium?

Comment: so you have to click on the iframe? does that change the "context" of the console perhaps? Note: console behaviour is rarely indicative of actual code behaviour

Comment: Are you trying to query google docs via chromium console or what exactly is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that 'problem' was with the scope:
[image: chromium devtools console scope]

In the video we can see that click changes it.